# Mapping a matrix in a binary file into Perl

Tags: perl, matrix

I have a 14 MB file with a matrix, in raw binary format. I would like to slurp it and have something like an array of arrays, so I can read some values. I was hoping to find some magical Perl module that would, given the size of the matrix, do all the work for me :)

But I can't find it, and I suspect I'm just missing a more obvious way of doing it. PDL::IO::FlexRaw is close to what I need, although I'm a bit confused about the warning with strange characters added by F77.

The matrix is in a binary file, in raw format, in 64 bits floats. The first eight bytes of the binary file is the first "cell" of the matrix, (1,1). The next eight bytes are the second cell, (2,1). It has no header and no footer. I know its dimensions, so I can tell the module "I have a row for every 64000 bytes".

I'm looking at tie::mmapArray, but I don't know if I can make it work. Maybe I better using lseek() back and forth to find the eight bytes I need and then unpack() it?

What is the best way of doing that?

Comment: What does "raw binary format" mean? The file is all ASCII 1s and 0s, with a new line in the file representing a new row of the matrix?

Comment: Diego, I moved your reply into the main question so it's clearer for people to know what you're asking.  You can always (and are encouraged!) to edit and update your main question with clarifications.  :)

Comment: `readflex('filename',[ { Type=>'double', NDims=>2, Dims=>[64000,28] } ]` would read in a raw format binary double format file of 14336000 bytes in size.  See [PDL::IO::FlexRaw docs](http://search.cpan.org/~chm/PDL-2.4.10/IO/FlexRaw/FlexRaw.pm) for more details and examples.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're tight on memory, just read the whole file in.

```
$size = -s $filename;
open(DATA, $filename);
sysread DATA, $buffer, $size;
@floats = unpack("d*", $buffer);
$float2x1 = $floats[ 2 + (1-1)*$width ];
```

That should access (2,1). (I didn't test it, though...)

EDIT:

Ok, low memory version:

```
use Sys::Mmap;
new Sys::Mmap $buffer, -s $filename, $filename or die $!;
$float2x1 = unpack("d", substr($buffer,8*( (2-1) + (1-1)*$width ),8));
```

Just needs Sys::Mmap from CPAN.

Comment: Hi
   Thanks. That code makes perl use 1GB of memory. it's a bit too much, although it's a way of doing it.

 -- Diego

Comment: I've edited the answer to add a way of doing it which doesn't slurp up unnecessary memory.

Answer (score 0):

A look at [pack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) and [unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) (especially unpack) might put you on the right track, look at the b format.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the structure of your file, how could any library hope to read it? If it's some kind of standardized matrix binary format, then you could try searching [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/) for that. Otherwise, I'm guessing you'll have to do the work yourself.

Assuming it's not a [sparse matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix), it's probably just a matter of reading in the dimensions, and then reading in appropriately sized blocks.